# How to search a string in an object in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I have data stored in this form

> "status": {
> "634feb9a5723003699a87e1e": "ACTIVE",
> "634ff0b95723003699a88054": "ACTIVE"
>   }

this status is an object. Here you can see the keys are mongodb objectIds, I want to find those documents where any child of the status has value "INACTIVE".

I've tried using regex in mongodb compass like this

> {status:/"INACTIVE"/i}

But I think this method only works in string array. Please tell me how can I do that with objects?

Comment: *this status is an array of objects.*, no it's not an array, from your attached data, it is any object with dynamic keys.

Comment: @YongShun its an array, but I don't know why mongodb compass is not showing it in json format. But I know this is an array

Comment: Can you share the original document?

Comment: @YongShun Yes you were right, Its an object. I've edited my question now

Comment: @YongShun your answer is absolutely right, what If I want to add another condition in this query? like I want to check another field. inactiveTill and condition for that is inactiveTill: { $lt: new Date() },

Comment: Like I want to get the documents whose statuses are INACTIVE and inactiveTill should be less than current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `status` is an object with dynamic keys, filtering the `status` object containing the "INACTIVE" value without the concern of dynamic keys:

`$expr` - Using aggregation operator.

`$ne` - Compare the result is not equal to an empty array.

`$filter`:

> `input`: `$objectToArray` - Convert the object into an array with objects containing `k` and `v` properties.
>
> `cond`: With `$regexMatch` operator to filter the document with the value of `v` matching the regex pattern.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $objectToArray: "$status"
          },
          cond: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: "$$this.v",
              regex: "INACTIVE",
              options: "i"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      []
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kunoxFydHn6)